# Getting Output of my Python code to a csv file

Tags: python

I am writing a python code to pull a list and give the output in a .CSV file .
The code is splitting after each character instead of each name .
The [Name] in the below code contains a list of names like :
aeims
aelog
amscompatibilitytool

```
with open("csvtest.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter='\t', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for namespace in namespaces:
        writer.writerows(namespace['name'])
```

Expected :

```
aeims
aelog
amscompatibilitytool
cgr
```

Result I am getting in csv file :

```
a
e
i
m
s
a
e
l
o
g
a
m
```

.... so on

Comment: can you please format code more better. just select all code and click on format button.

Comment: Can you show us what your `namespaces` var looks like?

Comment: namespace is a class name which is pulling the list from a node

Comment: One more doubt , if i add another write statement , and want the output of that in the 2nd column of the csv file , is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`writerows` writes [multiple rows](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to your csv file:

> Write all elements in rows (an iterable of row objects as described
>   above) to the writer’s file object, formatted according to the current
>   dialect.

Try to use `writerow` instead:

> Write the row parameter to the writer’s file object, formatted
>   according to the current dialect.

Like This:

```
with open("csvtest.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter='\t', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for namespace in namespaces:
        writer.writerow(namespace['name'])
```

Comment: One more doubt , it i add another write statement , and want the output of that in the 2nd column of the csv file , is there a way to do that ?